# How can i change inner html by using attribute for value using jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes, label, innerhtml

How can I change inner html by using attribute for value using jquery?

```html
<label for="name">Name</label>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<label for="message">Message</label>
```

Change to be:

```
<label for="name">NOMBRE</label>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<label for="phone">TELEFONO</label>
<label for="message">MENSAJE</label>
```

Comment: Care to elaborate and post  something you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can change them like this

```
$("label[for='name']").html("NOMBRE")
```